# Adobe XD textbox grow until max width then wrap

Tags: adobe-xd, text-wrap

My desired outcome is to have a textbox that grows (width-wise) with the first line of text, if/when the text is long enough to wrap I would like it to stop growing width-wise and wrap onto the next line.

Is this possible in Adobe XD?

Comment: Please add an example with dimensions. And how do you define "long enough to wrap"? Normally text wraps when longer than a textbox, but you want a growing text box. Therefore you need to give more detail. And will your textbox even be visible? Will it have a visible border or a background fill? Or what is the reason you want it to grow?